# How can I prove $\left(a+ \frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+ \frac{1}{b}\right)^2\ge \frac{25}{2}$, if $a+b = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For $a,b \in \mathbb R^+$ such that $a+b=1$, then:

$$\left(a+ \frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+ \frac{1}{b}\right)^2\ge \frac{25}{2}$$

Comment: Have you tried substituting $1-a$ for $b$ in the left side and expanding terms?  Where did you get? I haven't done it, but it seems the obvious thing to try.

Comment: I suppose you mean $a,b>0$. The statement is not true with e.g. a=-0.5 and b=1.5

Comment: Since it's a famous problem, I am wondering if you have tried google.

Comment: @CaveJohnson: it's more fun here ...

Comment: It's a AM/GM issure.  replace $a$ with $1/2 + k$ and $b$ with $1/2 -k$ and prove $((1/2 +k) + 1/(1/2+k))^2 + ((1/2 - k) + 1/(12 - k))^2  \ge (1/2 + 1/(1/2))^2 + (1/2 + 1/(1/2))^2 = (5/2)^2 + (5/2)^2 = 2*(25/4) = 25/2$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^2$ is convex then
$$\left(a+ \frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+ \frac{1}{b}\right)^2\geq 2\left(\frac{a+ \frac{1}{a}+b+ \frac{1}{b}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}\right)^2$$
So it suffices to show that
$$\frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}\geq 4$$
which holds because $\frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{1}{a(1-a)}$.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose $a,b\geq 0$. By AM-QM we obtain
$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(a+ \frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+\frac1b\right)^2}{2}}\geq \frac{\left(a+ \frac{1}{a}\right)+\left(b+\frac1b\right)}{2}=\frac{(a+b)+\left(\frac{a+b}{ab}\right)}{2}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{ab}}{2}.$$
By AM-GM
$$ab\leq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=\frac14$$
therefore
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{ab}}{2}\geq \frac52$$
and taking the squares we conclude.

Comment: Just a quick tidbit about mathjax: instead of, e.g., $$(a+\frac 1a)^2$$ as you used, you can type `\left(a +\frac 1a \right)^2` to get $$\left(a + \frac 1a \right)^2$$

Comment: @amWhy Yes, in fact I usually do. I'll edit thanks

Answer (score 1):

expanding we get $$a^2+1/a^2+b^2+1/b^2\geq \frac{17}{2}$$
this is equivalent to
$$a^2+b^2+\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2b^2}\geq \frac{17}{2}$$
this is equivalent to
$$(a^2+b^2)\left(1+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}\right)\geq \frac{17}{2}$$
from $a+b=1$ we get $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$ and $$\frac{1}{ab}\geq 2$$
thus we get  $$1+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}\geq 5$$
now you will need $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}$$